# Convert JSON from Firebase to GeoJSON and display on map

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, openlayers, geojson

I have a JSON file in Firebase (I am stuck using Firebase as my DB) that I am converting to a GeoJSON and trying to display with Open Layers 4. I have successfully written the conversion and verified the output is valid GeoJSON (using geojsonlint.com).

I do this all within JavaScript/React 16 and I do not save the file anywhere. I am simply trying to pass the converted object right into Open Layers to render as a vector tile. Open Layers requires a `url` for the input and rejects it when I try to load in a variable or function that returns the converted GeoJSON.

```
const testing = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource({
    url: '${getGeoJsonObject()}.geojson',
    format: new GeoJSON()
  })
});
```

Note, I have tried passing in a variable and, tried with and without `.json` and `.geojson`, at the end of `url:`.The error message is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
>      at JSON.parse ()`

It seems that OpenLayers is expecting an actual URL to grab the .geojson from, is there a way to trick it into grabbing the object? Or is there a way to use local storage? Perhaps another way entirely to load the object?

helper functions to convert Firebase to GeoJSON: [github](https://github.com/amillion3/fix-that-pothole/tree/aaa9428e008c2e1d165ec3f9f96d28e01d047848/src/helperFunctions)

(note, the helperFunctions have been tweaked a little bit, mainly to fix the coordinates to be properly outputted as an array and not as a string)

actual GeoJSON loading here: [line 48](https://github.com/amillion3/fix-that-pothole/blob/aaa9428e008c2e1d165ec3f9f96d28e01d047848/src/Components/Map/Map.js)

Comment: In OpenLayers can you use a custom loader rather than the url to set the vector source? http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector.html

Comment: "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" I usually see this when the request failed for some reason and the response is HTML rather than JSON. Take a look at the actual response for a potential clue

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I do believe the problem is that OpenLayers is expecting a remote file, but I am trying to just pass in an object. I can't seem to find a workaround to just dump in the object or a function. I have tried JSON.stringify as well as trying to make a 'fake' ajax call that sources the function as the URL. No dice. I'm not sure if there is a better phrase I can google or some other way to describe my problem.

Comment: I am trying this too. But now I am thinking that the data I upload to firebase, I will instead upload the data as a formatted JSON file instead and read it from storage.